# Dynamically create and nest DIV items from a json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm new to Javascript so this may not be the best approach.  I'm doing [Bellycard's web app challenge #1](https://tech.bellycard.com/join/) for fun.

I query their search endpoint, which returns JSON, something like this: https://rdio-service.herokuapp.com/search?q=korn (click it)

I get the unique search type:

```
//artist, album, tracks
var searchTypes = $.unique(data.data.map(function(d) {return d.type}));
```

Then I iterate `searchTypes` and filter the original `data` JSON for **that** `searchType`.  I learned how to `.appendChild` to an existing item on the GUI just fine.  But I don't know how to display the results under each `searchType`.  Code below.

```
//iterate searchTypes and display them foreach searchType
for(var i = 0; i < searchTypes.length; i++)
{
    var searchType = searchTypes[i];
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.id = searchType + "Result";

    //and then, each search type should have results for their type
    //select specific type for this iteration and put it in a results array
    var resultsThisType = data.data.filter(function (f) {
        return f.type ==  searchType;
    });

    for(var j = 0; j < resultsThisType.length; j++) {
        var newP = document.createElement('p'); //put it in a 'p' item for now, for testing
        newP.id = searchType + i + j;
        newP.innerHTML = resultsThisType[i].name; //test
        document.getElementById(searchType + "Result").appendChild(newP); //error here... what's the right approach?
    }

    newDiv.className = "typeResult";
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<h2>" + searchType + "</h2>";
    document.getElementById("results").appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Comment: Got it, typing up answer...

Comment: `document.getElementById(searchType + "Result")` is null and no such method as .appendChild.

Comment: can you set it up in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to find the div you "created" before it was added to the DOM. In your code, you create a parent div with this:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.id = searchType + "Result";
```

But you never add `newDiv` to the DOM structure on the page. Therefore, it only exists in memory until your last line here:

```
document.getElementById("results").appendChild(newDiv);
```

So when you try to find the element here:

```
document.getElementById(searchType + "Result").appendChild(newP);
```

The element can't be found and the method doesn't exist because `getElementById()` returns `null` since no element exists in the DOM with that ID.

Instead, what you need to do in this case is to use the actual parent variable like this:

```
newDiv.appendChild(newP);
```

See, `document.getElementByID()` only finds elements currently added to the DOM structure. It won't find anything that is in memory. That's why you need to use the actual variable you created prior. Once you add `newDiv` to the DOM on that last line it, and all it's children, will be added.

Another option would be to add `newDiv` to the DOM right after creating it and before making it's child elements. THEN and only then can you use `getElementByID()` and access the element.

It might be up for debate exactly which order to do it. But in some cases you might want to add the parent (`newDiv`) ONLY when it has children. So in that case you would want to wait to add it to the DOM until you know for sure it has children.